# How to step into the virtual function of derived class using GDB?

Tags: c++, gdb

Supposed that there is a base class and two derived classes, the base class has a pure virtual function named `greeting()`, both two derived classes inherit `greeting()` from the base class and implement their own `greeting()` respectively.

Then there is a `std::map<std::string, Base*> obj_map` which stores the object names and the corresponding address.

Now I am getting the object pointer through `obj_map` by given object name, then use `->` to call `greeting()`.

The problem is that, if I step into the line using gdb when `obj_map["..."]->greeting()` is called, gdb cannot stop at the `greeting()` of derived class, but at `operator[](key_type&& __k)` of `std::map`.

```cpp
    /*
     * @Author: dylan
     * @Date: 2022-09-08 01:09:20
     * @LastEditTime: 2022-09-08 01:18:34
     * @LastEditors: dylan
     * @Description: 
     * @FilePath: /cpptest/debug-derived-virtual-function/main.cc
     */
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <map>
    
    class Base {
    public:
        Base(const std::string &obj_name) : name(obj_name) { }
        virtual void greeting() = 0;
    protected:
        std::string name;
    };
    
    class Derived_1 : public Base {
    public:
        Derived_1(const std::string &obj_name) : Base(obj_name) { }
        void greeting() override {
            std::cout << "Hello, I am " << name << "!" << std::endl;
        }
    };
    
    class Derived_2 : public Base {
    public:
        Derived_2(const std::string &obj_name) : Base(obj_name) { }
        void greeting() override {
            std::cout << "Bonjour, c'est " << name << "!" << std::endl;
        }
    };
    
    int main()
    {
        Derived_1 derived_1("Ben");
        Derived_2 derived_2("Anaise");
    
        std::map<std::string, Base*> obj_map;
    
        obj_map["Ben"] = &derived_1;
        obj_map["Anaise"] = &derived_2;
    
        obj_map["Ben"]->greeting();
        obj_map["Anaise"]->greeting();
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Execute `g++ -g3 -Wall -O0 main.cc -o main` to compile.

The debug information is below:

```
    (gdb) 
    41
    42          std::map<std::string, Base*> obj_map;
    43
    44          obj_map["Ben"] = &derived_1;
    45          obj_map["Anaise"] = &derived_2;
    46
    47          obj_map["Ben"]->greeting();
    48          obj_map["Anaise"]->greeting();
    49
    50          return 0;
    (gdb) break 47
    Breakpoint 1 at 0x25c2: file main.cc, line 47.
    (gdb) run
    Starting program: /home/ubuntu/workspace/practice/cpptest/debug-derived-virtual-function/main 
    
    Breakpoint 1, main () at main.cc:47
    47          obj_map["Ben"]->greeting();
    (gdb) step
    std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Base*, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, Base*> > >::operator[] (
        this=0x7fffffffdda0, __k=...) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_map.h:510
    510           operator[](key_type&& __k)
    (gdb) n
    515             iterator __i = lower_bound(__k);
    (gdb) 
    517             if (__i == end() || key_comp()(__k, (*__i).first))
    (gdb) 
    521             return (*__i).second;
    (gdb) 
    522           }
    (gdb) 
    Hello, I am Ben!
    main () at main.cc:48
    48          obj_map["Anaise"]->greeting();
    (gdb) step
    std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Base*, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, Base*> > >::operator[] (
        this=0x7ffff7c393c6 <__GI__IO_fflush+134>, __k=...) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_map.h:510
    510           operator[](key_type&& __k)
    (gdb) n
    515             iterator __i = lower_bound(__k);
    (gdb) 
    517             if (__i == end() || key_comp()(__k, (*__i).first))
    (gdb) 
    521             return (*__i).second;
    (gdb) 
    522           }
    (gdb) 
    Bonjour, c'est Anaise!
    main () at main.cc:50
    50          return 0;
    (gdb)
```

As you can see, the gdb did not step into the corresponding `greeting()` of each derived class.
**So is it possible to let gdb step into the corresponding `greeting()` correctly?**

**APPEND: I am working on non-small project, every time I compile the project will take a lot of time. Is there any way can work without modifying the code? Maybe there are over 200 derived classes like this, so it's quite a hassle to figure out which function was actually called each time.**

Comment: `{auto& r = obj_map["..."]; r->greeting(); }`

Comment: Re: stops "at `operator[](key_type&& __k)`" -- keep on stepping. Or set a breakpoint at the appropriate `greeting()` and run.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot It works!  By the way, is there any way can work like this without modifying the code? Because I am working on non-small project, every time I compile the project will take a lot of time. Moreover, maybe there are over 200 derived classes like this, so it's quite a hassle to figure out which function was actually called. Thanks!

Comment: @PeteBecker For some reason, "keep on stepping" doesn't seem to work, gdb just stepped out. And yes, setting a breakpoint at the appropriate greeting() is the most direct solution. ^_^

Comment: "keep on stepping" works for me. But `advance greeting` works even better.

Comment: @PeteBecker Oh I tried again just now, it worked! But as @ssbssa said, using `advance` is better. Thanks.

Comment: @ssbssa Yes, `advance` is better. Nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two tricks I use for situations like this.  First is making use of the [finish](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html#index-finish) command, here's an example of it in use:

```
$ gdb -q test
Reading symbols from test...
(gdb) break 47
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401460: file test.cc, line 47.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/so/test 

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.cc:47
47    obj_map["Ben"]->greeting();
(gdb) step
std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Base*, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, Base*> > >::operator[] (this=0x7fffffffaba0, __k=...) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_map.h:515
515     iterator __i = lower_bound(__k);
(gdb) finish
Run till exit from #0  std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Base*, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, Base*> > >::operator[] (
    this=0x7fffffffaba0, __k=...) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_map.h:515
0x0000000000401497 in main () at test.cc:47
47    obj_map["Ben"]->greeting();
Value returned is $1 = (std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Base*, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, Base*> > >::mapped_type &) @0x419ef0: 0x7fffffffac00
(gdb) step
Derived_1::greeting (this=0x7fffffffac00) at test.cc:25
25      std::cout << "Hello, I am " << name << "!" << std::endl;
(gdb)
```

So once you step into the function that you're not interested in, just use `finish` to return to the caller, then `step` again to get where you want to go.

But, if that gets annoying, then its possible to automate the process using [skip function](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Skipping-Over-Functions-and-Files.html#index-skip-function), like this (continuing from the above session):

```
(gdb) skip function std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Base*, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, Base*> > >::operator[]
Function std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Base*, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, Base*> > >::operator[] will be skipped when stepping.
(gdb) run
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /tmp/so/test 

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.cc:47
47    obj_map["Ben"]->greeting();
(gdb) step
Derived_1::greeting (this=0x7fffffffac00) at test.cc:25
25      std::cout << "Hello, I am " << name << "!" << std::endl;
(gdb)
```

The text I pass to `skip function` is just copied directly from when I first stepped into the `std::map::operator[]` function, I didn't have to figure it out myself!  Now, when I `step` at line 47, GDB silently steps into, and then finishes, the `operator[]` call, and then does one more step, which moves us into `greeting`.

You can track which `skips` you have in place with `info skip`, and delete or disable them with `skip delete` and `skip disable`.

Comment: Oh I see! The first step to call `obj_map["Ben"]->greeting()` is to get the object address by calling `operator[]`, then access `greeting()` through the object address. So I should use `finish` or `skip` to skip the step one and use `step` to go into the corresponding `greeting()`. I understand this problem 100% now, thank you so much!